# What are Short Hand Guidelines? Want to use Xml.parseJS()

Tags: google-apps-script

Can anyone tell me where to find the "Short Hand guidelines" referred to here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_xml#parseJS

```
function createXmlDocument() {
  var elementName   = 'customerName';
  var customerName = 'Bad Boys Inc.';
  var parseJSparameter = [elementName, customerName];
  var xmlDoc = Xml.parseJS(parseJSparameter);
  var textOfXml = xmlDoc.toXmlString();
  Logger.log(textOfXml);
}

function createXmlDocument2() {
  var shortHand = ['customer', 
                   {'active' : 'true'},
                   ['name', 'Bad Boys Inc.'], 
                   ['customerId', '6060']
                  ];
  var xmlDoc = Xml.parseJS(shortHand);
  var textOfXml = shortHand.toXmlString();
  Logger.log(textOfXml);
}
```

createXmlDocument works but createXmlDocument2 doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had the same question, the only thing I could find is section 2 of the Soap Overview at:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/soap_overview

Comment: I found that too but cannot get my code to work and was looking for something more comprehensive. Were you successful at getting the code to work?

Answer (score 0):

It's no surprise that the latter snippet doesn't work as there're a few mistakes in it.
Try this:

```
function createXmlDocument2() {
    var shortHand = ['customer', 
                      ['active' , 'true'],
                      ['name', 'Bad Boys Inc.'], 
                      ['customerId', '6060']
                    ];
    var xmlDoc = Xml.parseJS(shortHand);
    var textOfXml = xmlDoc.toXmlString();
    Logger.log(textOfXml);
}
```